# Securing API with Azure AD and local accounts

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I want to secure my API so that only users authenticated in Azure AD and having local accounts in my application are able to call it. Fronted will be React SPA application. I already created PoC that authenticates users with Azure AD and I can call my API from SPA.

Now I would like to add support for local accounts. I thought about using ASP.NET Core Identity to manage local users. Then I would create endpoints for SPA to get JWT tokens. But I'm not sure if this is the way to go. I see examples of code generating tokens and it doesn't seem very hard to implement but this is security. Maybe it's not a good idea to ever do it yourself?

I see people are using IdentityServer4 and from what I've read it can also use my local ASP.NET Core Identity accounts and integrate with Azure Ad. But this would be another tool in my technology stack that I would need to learn. It would not be shared with any other applications and it would be another service that I need to deploy and manage. Maybe it's an overkill for this scenario?

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would like to add support for local accounts. I thought about using ASP.NET Core Identity to manage local users. Then I would create endpoints for SPA to get JWT tokens.

You can do that by adding endpoints in api for [token authentication](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) . Your client app pass the user's credential to web api , web api validates the credential from local database , and creates JWT token back to client app . For validation token , your web api will create two authentication schemes , one is for AAD token and one is for local database user's token .

> I see people are using IdentityServer4 and from what I've read it can also use my local ASP.NET Core Identity accounts and integrate with Azure Ad.

Identity Server 4 supports for external identity providers like Azure Active Directory and can use ASP.NET Core Identity as user management . If you understand the OpenID Connect , it is not difficult to implement and you can benefit from features like Single Sign-on / Sign-out . [Here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity) is code sample which combines the EF and ASP.NET Identity . You can just add external identity providers like AAD :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "<appID>";
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/";             
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-aadtenant";            
    options.SaveTokens = true;                                 
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

})
```

Comment: But my question is if I should ever issue JWT tokens for local accounts myself? Aren't I'm going to implement OIDC and OpenAuth myself then? Does this make any sense? After more reading I no longer think this is something I should do.

Comment: Using JWT in web api is good point , so when use local account , issue jwt token back to client . `After more reading I no longer think this is something I should do` and why ?

Comment: I meant creating it yourself.. I think you should stick to existing solutions which are built according to standards, well known and tested. Anyway I'm switching to Azure B2C.

Comment: Identity server4 is well document and have lots of code samples , if you accept Azure AD  B2C ,then use it .